# Directory in C# .Net

Tags: c#

I have :

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.*",
                                     SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

And, I want to know how many files in it. Can you help me?

Comment: -1. Does not show any research effort.

Comment: Intellisense FTW. I'm pretty sure you would have found the answer faster by browsing the options available to you.

Answer (score 4):

You simply query for how many items there are in the array.

```
int amountOfFiles = filePaths.Length;
```

Answer (score 3):

`filePaths.Length` should give you the number of files.

Answer (score 3):

You have an array of the files, so the array length will tell you the number of files.

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDir\", "*.*",
                                 SearchOption.AllDirectories);
int numberOfFiles = filePaths.Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

use the [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.length%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) property: `filePaths.Length`